# How can I lock most of a row when a specific cell has data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that provides part numbers for the weird and wonderful. It's basically complete when I realised that someone could accidentally change previous entries and break the whole thing! Database is in my sights, but for now Excel must do.

I want to lock Row X from columns A-K when something is in column L, the date. I'm currently using `Application.Intersect Target` to ensure no-one tries to leave blank rows or incomplete descriptions, but can't seem to get the addition of locking.

Current Sub looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim isect As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("E3:E9999"))

    If Not (isect Is Nothing) Then
        If Target.Column = 1 Then
            If Len(Target.Value) > 0 And Len(Target.Offset(-1, 2).Value) = 0 Then
'            Check if a row is skipped on Initials
                MsgBox "You cannot skip a row", vbInformation
                Target.ClearContents
            End If
        Else
            If (Len(Target.Value) > 0 And Len(Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value) = 0) Or (Len(Target.Value) > 0 And Len(Target.Offset(-1, 2).Value) = 0) Then
'             Check if previous part description is blank
                MsgBox "You cannot skip a row, or leave an incomplete part", vbInformation
                Target.ClearContents
            End If

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to lock the cells with the [Range.Locked property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.locked) and if you protect your sheet with the [Worksheet.Protect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect) all locked cells cannot be edited anymore. **NOTE** by default **all** cells of a sheet are `.locked = True` that means you need to unlock  everything that you want to be able to edit after your sheet is protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I solved this with a simple data validation `If(Next Cell = "",Named-List,FALSE)` to disable drop-down adjustment once a part has been created.